Server sent event (SSE) timing delays Golang backend React frontend
I'm trying to implement an AI chat interface with a typewriter effect like ChatGPT. My backend API is written in Go and uses sashabaranov/go-openai for interfacing with OpenAI. Here's the controller, which is served at the route /answer/api/v1/chat/completion
package controller

import (
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/apache/incubator-answer/internal/base/handler"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/sashabaranov/go-openai"
    "github.com/segmentfault/pacman/errors"
)

// ChatController chat controller
type ChatController struct{}

// NewChatController creates a new ChatController
func NewChatController() *ChatController {
    return &ChatController{}
}

// ChatCompletion godoc
// @Summary Get Chat Completion
// @Description Get Chat Completion
// @Tags api-answer
// @Accept  json
// @Produce  json
// @Param prompt query string true "Prompt for the chat completion"
// @Router /answer/api/v1/chat/completion [get]
// @Success 200 {object} map[string]interface{}
func (cc *ChatController) ChatCompletion(ctx *gin.Context) {
    prompt := ctx.Query("prompt")
    if prompt == "" {
        handler.HandleResponse(ctx, gin.Error{Err: errors.New(400, "prompt is required")}, nil)
        return
    }

    OPENAI_API_KEY := os.Getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

    client := openai.NewClient(OPENAI_API_KEY)
    stream, err := client.CreateChatCompletionStream(ctx, openai.ChatCompletionRequest{
        Model: "gpt-4",
        Messages: []openai.ChatCompletionMessage{
            {Role: "system", Content: "You are a helpful assistant."},
            {Role: "user", Content: prompt},
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        handler.HandleResponse(ctx, err, nil)
        return
    }
    defer stream.Close()

    ctx.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")
    ctx.Writer.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    ctx.Writer.Header().Set("Connection", "keep-alive")

    const NEWLINE = "$NEWLINE$"

    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        default:
            response, err := stream.Recv()
            if err != nil {
                handler.HandleResponse(ctx, err, nil)
                return
            }
            if response.Choices[0].Delta.Content != "" {
                contentWithNewlines := strings.ReplaceAll(response.Choices[0].Delta.Content, "\n", NEWLINE)
                ctx.Writer.Write([]byte("event: token\n"))
                ctx.Writer.Write([]byte("data: " + contentWithNewlines + "\n\n"))
                ctx.Writer.Flush()
            }
        }
    }
}

On the frontend I have a React page with an EventSource with a listener that should be outputting each token as it's received:
/* eslint-disable */
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';


const Chats = () => {
  const [output, setOutput] = useState<string>("");
  const [isStarted, setIsStarted] = useState(false);
  const [isStreamFinished, setIsStreamFinished] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const prompt = 'mic check'; // Replace with your actual prompt
  const NEWLINE = '$NEWLINE$'
  
  
  const startChat = useCallback(() => {
    setIsStarted(true);
    setOutput("");
    
    const eventSource = new EventSource(
      `/answer/api/v1/chat/completion?prompt=${encodeURIComponent(prompt)}`,
    );
    
    eventSource.addEventListener('error', () => eventSource.close());
    
    eventSource.addEventListener("token", (e) => {
      // avoid newlines getting messed up
      const token = e.data.replaceAll(NEWLINE, "\n");
      console.log(token);
      setOutput((prevOutput) => prevOutput + token);
    });
    
    eventSource.addEventListener("finished", (e) => {
      console.log("finished", e);
      eventSource.close();
      setIsStreamFinished(true);
    });
    
    return () => {
      eventSource.close();
    };
  }, [prompt]);
  

  
  return (
    <div>
    <p>Prompt: {prompt}</p>
    {!isStarted && <button onClick={startChat}>Start</button>}
    <div>{output}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chats;

What actually happens when I hit the Start button is that it pauses until the completion finishes and then all the tokens are output at once. If I have a prompt that generates a longer response, that upfront pause is longer and still all the tokens are output at once. I'm not sure if the delay is on the frontend or backend.
I've tried logging tokens to the console every time the token EventListener is triggered, and confirmed that there's an upfront delay that varies based on the size of the response and then all tokens are logged to the console at once.
I was expecting that each token would arrive, one by one, in a stream with each one outputting to the console as it arrived.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
